# (httplog)-static: issbsettingenabled false android

Tags: android, servlets, https, adb, android-logcat

I am developing Android app and running in Samsung J7. The problem is while running the app it show the error "**(httplog)-static: issbsettingenabled false**"  is there any way to enable httplog true or an alternative way to solve this.  If programmatially want to enable this how to do that

```
private void tryLogin(String log, String pass) {


            HttpURLConnection connection;
               OutputStreamWriter request = null;

                    URL url = null;   
                    String response = null;         
                    String parameters = "="+log+"&="+pass;   

                    try
                    {
                         url = new URL("http://209.68.26.95/anglertechnologieseit/lc_webservice/webservice.php?Case=loginCheck");
                        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        connection.setDoOutput(true);
                        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");    

                        request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                        request.write(parameters);
                        request.flush();
                        request.close();            
                        String line = "";               
                        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                       stored in response variable.                
                        response = sb.toString();

                    Toast.makeText(this,"Message from Server: \n"+ response, 0).show();             

                        System.out.println("Message from Serverrrrrrrrrrrr     :"+response);
                        isr.close();
                        reader.close();

                    }
                    catch(IOException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("eeerrrrooorrr"+e);
                    }

        }
```

[image]

Comment: HI Vivil any solution on this??

Comment: Still nothing found?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer its a FTP credential problem in the demo server.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more a warning than an error. If you get spammed by these messages you can deactivate this certain type of Error (there are other questions on Stackoverflow).

I first thought this would be an error because I did not receive any data on my server.

My mistake was that the Code did not work probably. (Forgot to ask for the response code)
This Code work probably:

```
try { System.out.println("HTTP Upload");
        URL Singin_url = new URL("http://192.168.0.157:80");
        HttpURLConnection client = (HttpURLConnection)          
        Singin_url.openConnection();
        client.setRequestMethod("POST");
        client.setDoOutput(true);
        client.setDoInput(true);
        client.setConnectTimeout(10000); // 5 sec
        client.setReadTimeout(10000);

        OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
        String data = "POST_FROM_MOBILE";
        writer.write(data);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        out.close();
        Log.e("E", String.valueOf(client.getResponseCode()));
    }catch(MalformedURLException error) {
        Log.e("Error","Wrong URL");
    }
    catch(SocketTimeoutException error) {
        Log.e("Error","Timeout");

    }
    catch (IOException error) {
        Log.e("Error","IOException Error");
    }
```

Tip: It is easier to debug with the Debugger Mode because you will see more Errors